# create an array based on the values in 2 existing arrays

Tags: php, arrays

i have 2 arrays :-

```
Array ( [0] => 15 
        [1] => 15 
        [2] => 18 
        [3] => 18 
        [4] => 19 
        [5] => 21 
        [6] => 21 
        [7] => 21 )

Array ( [0] => 13 
        [1] => 14 
        [2] => 16 
        [3] => 17 
        [4] => 20 
        [5] => 22 
        [6] => 23 
        [7] => 24 )
```

n i want a third array such that :-

```
Array ( [0] => 15 
        [1] => 13 
        [2] => 14 
        [3] => 18 
        [4] => 16 
        [5] => 17 
        [6] => 19 
        [7] => 20 
        [8] => 21 
        [9] => 22 
        [10] => 23 
        [11] => 24 )
```

Relation between the 3 arrays is this that, first array element has got to be first element of the third array and then since first element occurs exactly 2 times in the first array, so the next two elements of the third array will be picked up from the second array. Pls guide ?

Comment: Theres a manual which tells you about array functions http://www.php.net//manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: i know there's a manual but i am unable to solve this problem ? kindly help ...

Comment: I don't quite get it. Why do you have 18 as the 4th element of the 3rd array? Is it because 19 appears only one, so you need to pick the element from the first array, and since you're filling the 4th element you pick the 4th element of the first array? Doesn't make sense, because you already went through the pair of 18.

Comment: This is a very unusual way to combine two arrays, and I think that a simple `for` loop through the first array is the best way to go. Use a variable to store each element so you can count how often it's repeated, then apply your logic.

Comment: hi amenadiel, sorry for the late reply. array is constructed like this that the 1st element of 1st array is the 1st element of 3rd array and then the number of times it is repeated in the 1st array, we have to pick up those many elements from the second array to fill up the 3rd array and same technique is used for the rest of the elements as well.. for example, 15 is repeated 2 times so we get 15, 13, 14 as first three elements then 18 is chosen as the 4th followed by 16, 17 as the next two in the 3rd array as 18 is repeated 2 times as well.. then 19 and 20 as no repetition is there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$rightSide = array(15, 15, 15, 15, 18, 18, 19, 21, 21, 21, 25, 25);
$leftSide = array(13, 14, 12, 11, 16, 17, 20, 22, 23, 24, 30, 31);
$rightFlip = array_flip($rightSide);

for($k=0; $k<count($rightFlip); $k++)
{
    $arr25[$k] = $k;
}

$array25 = array_combine($arr25, $rightFlip);

$k = 0;
while($k<count($array25))
{
    if($k==0)
    {
        $finArr[0] = $rightSide[0];
        $repeat_0 = $array25[0] - (-1);
        echo "Repeat_0 = " . $repeat_0. "</br>";
        for($i=0; $i<$repeat_0; $i++)
        {
            $finArr[$i+1] = $leftSide[$i];
        }
    }
/*  
    else if($k==1)
    {
        $repeat = $array25[$k] - $array25[$k-1];
        $repeatPrev = $array25[$k-1] - $repeat[$k-2];
        $insideUsed = $repeat_0;
        $finArr[$i+1] = $rightSide[$repeat_0];

        for($j=$i+2; $j<($repeat+$i+2); $j++)
        {

            $finArr[$j] = $leftSide[$insideUsed];
            $insideUsed = $insideUsed + 1;
        }
    }
    else if($k==2)
    {
        $repeat = $array25[$k] - $array25[$k-1];
        $repeatPrev = $array25[$k-1] - $array25[$k-2];
        echo "Repeat = " . $repeat. "</br>";
        echo "RepeatPrev = " . $repeatPrev. "</br>";
        $finArr[$j] = $rightSide[$repeat_0 + $repeatPrev];
        $insideUsed = $repeat_0 + $repeatPrev;
        for($l=$j+1; $l<($repeat+$j+1); $l++)
        {
            $finArr[$l] = $leftSide[$insideUsed];
            $insideUsed = $insideUsed + 1;
        }
    }
/*    else if($k==3)
    {
        $repeat = $array25[$k] - $array25[$k-1];
        $repeatPrev = $array25[$k-1] - $array25[$k-2];
        $repeatPrevPrev = $array25[$k-2] - $array25[$k-3];
        $finArr[$l] = $rightSide[$repeat_0 + $repeatPrevPrev + $repeatPrev];
        $insideUsed = $repeat_0 + $repeatPrevPrev + $repeatPrev;
        for($m=$l+1; $m<($repeat+$l+1); $m++)
        {
            $finArr[$m] = $leftSide[$insideUsed];
            $insideUsed = $insideUsed + 1;
        }
    }*/
    else 
    {
        echo "</br> for k = " . $k . "</br>";
        for($n=$k; $n>0; $n--)
        {
            $repeat_arr[$n] = $array25[$n] - $array25[$n-1];
            echo "Repeat_arr[". $n . "] = ". $repeat_arr[$n];
        }

        $repeat_arr[0] = $array25[0] - (-1);
        echo "Repeat_arr 0 = " . $repeat_arr[0];

        for($I=0; $I<$k; $I++)
        {
            $addRepeats[$k] += $repeat_arr[$I];
        }

        $addRepeats[$k] += $k;

        echo "addRepeats = " . $addRepeats[$k];

        for($I=0; $I<$k; $I++)
        {
            $added[$k] += $repeat_arr[$I];
        }

        $finArr[$addRepeats[$k]] = $rightSide[$added[$k]];

        for($I=$addRepeats[$k]+1; $I<($repeat_arr[$k] + $addRepeats[$k] + 1); $I++)
        {
            $finArr[$I] = $leftSide[$added[$k]];
            $added[$k] = $added[$k] + 1;
        }

    }

    $k++;

}




echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Array25</th>";
echo "<th>RightSide</th>";
echo "<th>LeftSide</th>";
echo "<th>finArr</th>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array25);
echo "</pre>";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rightSide);
echo "</pre>";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($leftSide);
echo "</pre>";
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finArr);
echo "</pre>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
```

This answer will be correct no matter how many elements are added or subtracted from rightside array and corresponding elements added / subtracted from left side array.. to make changes in array25 array......

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
   $f1 =  array ( 0 => 15 ,
    1 => 15 ,
    2 => 18 ,
    3 => 18 ,
    4 => 19, 
    5 => 21 ,
    6 => 21, 
    7 => 21 );

   $f2 =  array ( 0 => 13, 
    1 => 14 ,
    2 => 16 ,
    3 => 17 ,
    4 => 20 ,
    5 => 22 ,
    6 => 23 ,
    7 => 24 ) ;

    $result = array_merge((array)$f1, (array)$f2);
    $input = array_unique($result);
    print_r($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_combine() or array_merge then array_flip() function..if the value are unique use array_unique()

you have to use array_flip() to change value as a key.